# How to sleep for a fixed period of time not affected by system clock adjustment in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, time, thread-sleep

I was using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` to sleep for a second. I found that if I adjust the system time backwards during the sleep, the sleep time would extend for the amount of time I just adjusted.

But `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` is supposed to work regardless of system time unlike `std::this_thread::sleep_until()`, which probably should exhibit the behavior mentioned above.

When I look at the Visual C++ 2012's implementation of `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`, I found

```
template<class _Rep,
class _Period> inline
void sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Rel_time)
{   // sleep for duration
stdext::threads::xtime _Tgt = _To_xtime(_Rel_time);
sleep_until(&_Tgt);
}
```

So `sleep_for()` is implemented using `sleep_until()` in Visual C++ 2012. I searched the C++11 standard, and it doesn't really forbid this kind of implementation. So how can I get to sleep for a fixed period of time not affected by system clock adjustment?

Comment: It does work independent of system clock adjustments. The system's best guess of wall clock time after the sleep was one second more than the system's best guess of wall clock time before the sleep. Imagine if the clock was slow and you slept for a day, you would want the clock adjustments to correct the sleep time -- ignoring them would be incorrect.

Comment: Use `sleep_until` with a steady_clock?

Comment: `steady_clock` of VC2012 is not steady: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753063/

Comment: The intent of 30.2.4 Timing specifications [thread.req.timing] is to outlaw this implementation for exactly the reasons you state.  Without such requirements the intended difference in functionality between the `_for` and `_until` functions is greatly diminished.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Can't believe I missed that! You are right. So the problem is VC++ 2012's implementation of `sleep_for` does not conform to the standard. Considering the `steady_clock` issue where those supposed different clocks are just implemented as `typedef`s of one another. The `chrono` part seems to be rushed out.

Comment: FYI I just tried using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono:milliseconds(250))` in Visual Studio 11 (Visual Studio 2012) and it seems to sleep for 250 ms regardless of how I adjust the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [timer queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) these are precision relative timers. To make the timer waitable, have your timer routine trigger an event as in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @WiSaGaN All the portable ways have major issues. Timing is something that is just not portable without an additional library that makes it so, like network I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in Windows 10 with the VS 2017 compiler. `sleep_for` still blocks if you turn back the system clock.

[The Windows `Sleep` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) works properly and only sleeps for the specified amount of time.